# Constructor can't accept input type Expression<Func<T, TResult>> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, expression

I want to create the class `Foo` as follows.

The `Foo` constructor input expression has to get some member of `Type T` to do some work.

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector)
    {
         List<string> memberNames = typeof(TR).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
         ....//some work on memberNames 
    }
}
```

and create `Foo<T>` instance by this code:

```
Foo<ClassA> foo = new Foo<ClassA>(u=>new{u.Property1, u.Property2});
```

However, this did not work and gave the following error:

```
Constructor can't have Generic type TResult.
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:

After struggling to understand the expression I found an answer and have written it as an answer.

Comment: `Foo<T>` cannot have a constructor `Foo<SomethingElse>`

Comment: As far as I know you can't use `TResult` like that. It needs to be set on a method, or you need to add `TResult` to the class definition like so: `Foo<T, TResult>`.

Comment: yes, that isn't compile, but I want that work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve that as follow

```
class ClassA
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}    
class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(Expression<Func<T, Object>> selector)
    {
        var props = ((NewExpression)selector.Body).Members.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
    }
}

Foo<ClassA> foo = new Foo<ClassA>(u => new { u.MyProperty, u.MyProperty2 });
```

Comment: thanks Evk. it won't compile. I correct that. so this answer is best.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the logic outside of consrtuctor to separate method. Instead of using constructor to create Foo - you can use static method, like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
    private Foo() {

    }

    private void Init<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector) {
        List<string> memberNames = typeof(TResult).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        //some work on memberNames 
    }

    public static Foo<T> Create<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> selector) {
        var foo = new Foo<T>();
        foo.Init(selector);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Foo<ClassA> foo = Foo<ClassA>.Create(u=>new{u.Property1, u.Property2});
```